# atributo de un objeto mediante this

Tags: javascript

Hola estoy creando un objeto simple en js mediante el cual tiene id, y slug. la gracia  es que el mediante this pueda acceder a el id de este, cuando pido la salida del objeto me da un valor undefined.

```js
    const post = {
      id: 1,
      slug: `post-${this.id}`
    }

    console.log(post);
```

Comment: el this alli es window es global

Comment: `slug` tiene que ser una función, entonces podrás usar `this` en el contexto adecuado: `slug: function() { return \`post-${this.id}\`; }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Necesitas una función para cambiar el contexto y con ello el valor de `this` y así poder usar el `id`:

```js
const arrayDePost = [];
let post = {
    id: 1,
    slug: function() { return `post-${this.id}` },
};

arrayDePost.push(post);

post = {
    id: 2,
    slug: function() { return `post-${this.id}` },
};

arrayDePost.push(post);

console.log(arrayDePost[0].slug());
console.log(arrayDePost[1].slug());
```

Una función anónima puede dar resultados erróneos por no cambiar el contexto, no estarías usando el valor del objeto.

Answer (score 1):

puedes meterlo dentro de un metodo anonimo y de esta manera encapsular el valor y el resultado, el detalle es que accederias a el como metodo

```js
const post = {
  id: 1,
  slug: () => `post-${post.id}`
}

console.log(post.slug());
post.id = 5;
console.log(post.slug());
```

Comment: En tu respuesta, si cambia el valor de `post`, ya no funciona. Necesitas una función que no sea anónima.

Comment: si sigue funcionando, el problema es cuando se quiere replicar el mismo objeto, como todo funciona anonimamente, solo hace scope a ese mismo valor @ArianJM

Comment: Lo que quiero decir con "no funciona" es que estás usando el valor de `post.id` del contexto de `window`. No el del objeto. Si `post` fuera una variable `let`, y la almacenaras en un array, más adelante hicieras `post = { id: 'Hello' };`, ya no puedes acceder al `id` del `post` almacenado en el array. Prueba el código de mi respuesta con tu función anónima y verás lo que quiero decir. Te saldrá dos veces `post-2` en consola.

Comment: ajá, a eso me referia con `el problema es cuando se quiere replicar el mismo objeto` @ArianJM